# Render attributes after they are deleted. Spring MVC, Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, attributes

Good day folks. I have DAO method to delete some files.

```
@Override
    public void deleteFormDescription(Date formDate, String institutionName) {

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Integer dateId = fetchDateId(formDate);
        Integer institutionId = fetchInstitutionId(institutionName);

            if(dateId == null && institutionId == null) {
                throw new UnexpectedRollbackException("Transaction will roll back because, dateId: " + dateId + " and institutionId: " + institutionId);
            }

        try {

            FormDescription formDescription = (FormDescription)session.createCriteria(FormDescription.class, "formDescription")
                                                                        .createAlias("formDescription.institutions", "institution").add(Restrictions.eq("institution.institutionId", institutionId))
                                                                                    .createAlias("formDescription.formDate", "formDate").add(Restrictions.eq("formDate.dateId", dateId)).uniqueResult();
            session.delete(formDescription);
            session.flush();

        } catch(RuntimeException e) {       
            throw new UnexpectedRollbackException("Transaction will roll back because " +
                                                                " method deleteFormDescription(Date formDate, String institutionName) could not delete an FormDescription");
        }

    }
```

And in my Controller  I have:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/deleteprocessing", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteProcessing(@RequestParam String particularDate,
                               @RequestParam String institutionName) throws Exception {

            educationWebService.deleteFormDescriptionService(dateConvertation(particularDate), institutionName);    

    return "redirect:/delete";
}
```

I need this method render on JSP page which files his delete. Is it possible to do this? Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible. After deleting, keep a **detached** instance of the deleted FormDescription entity object and pass it to your JSP for displaying.

Keep in mind as soon as your transaction commits and Hibernate session is closed your entity objects are (should be) in detached state.